# How to pass res from one function to another?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
FB.api('4', function (res) {
  if(!res || res.error) {
   console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
   return;
  }
  console.log(res.id);
  console.log(res.name);
});

// viewed at http://localhost:8080
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));

});
```

Ive created this small FB.api call which return some data. Now I want to display this data when accessing localhost:8080/test, how do I do that? what is the way to do stuff like that? Can someone point me to some documentation of possible?

Comment: Nest call to `FB.api` inside `app.get` (you will need to rename `res` to `FBres` to avoid collision with `app.get` `res`) then in `FB.api` callback read from `FBres` and write to `res` and voila. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285735/express-js-execution-flow-using-callbacks

Comment: @csharpfolk Well thanks! Aint no Csharp but you know your stuff! Thanks for the link also, any good documentation you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you add your FB.api call inside an express route like this

```
app.get('/something', function(req, res) {
    FB.api('4', function (result) {
        if(!res || res.error) {
            return res.send(500, 'error');
        }

        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

Then inside index.html you can add some javascript to your page and create an XHR to call 'localhost:8080/something' like that

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/something');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            var data = xhr.responseText;

            //Do whatever you want with this data.
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this did it for me. Any good documentation you recommend?

Comment: I don't know what kind of documentation you need but you can visit http://expressjs.com/ they got a solid documentation for their api also if you need more information on XHR i recommend you to visit mozilla for the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest also there is this article that you can find at html5rocks https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/ which is really cool

Comment: Thanks, thats what i've been looking for.